# Get mouse coordinates when mouse stop or change direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

I get mouse position with simple code:

```
$("#container").mousemove( function(e) {

    client_x = e.pageX;
    client_y = e.pageY;

        // save coordinates

});
```

But I need only the start and stop coordinates + coordinates when mouse change direction, so I can "copy" mouse movements.

I think I need some kind of timer to see if mouse stoped for some interval?

Comment: 1:[{"x":"681","y":"144"},
2:{"x":"681","y":"145"},
3:{"x":"681","y":"146"},
4:{"x":"680","y":"147"},
5:{"x":"680","y":"148"},
In instance 4 the direction changed for X, but for Y is changing always in this example.

Comment: First I would need to detect stop and start position (that is only stop position)

Comment: I think this is quite useless.The mouse almost always moves diagonally.

Comment: @MaxArt, you are right.
I think i'm gonna get stop coordinate + get coordinate every X interval. Because I'm gonna animate mouse movement afretwards, and I only need **stop** position and their is to much data to save and animate from every position of mouse

Comment: Old question, but was linked.  If you only want the mouse coordinates when the mouse stops, then you can `debounce` the mousemove event.   Not the same for "change direction" though - what does that even mean?    Isn't that just a move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timer, timer2 = 0, client_x, client_y; //I made them global since it's easier
$("#container").mousemove( function(e) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  client_x = e.pageX;
  client_y = e.pageY;
  if((new Date()).getTime() > timer2 + 2000) {
    timer2 = (new Date()).getTime(); //just in case this event handler gets called again before the timer runs doCopy
    setTimeout(doCopy, 1); //run "outside" the event handler (since it's not good for an event handler to take a long time
  } else {
    timer = setTimeout(doCopy, 1000);
  }
});

function doCopy() {
  timer2 = (new Date()).getTime();
  .....
}
```

This is constantly settings and clearing timers. If the mouse stops for 1 second the `doCopy()` function gets triggered.

Comment: This doesn't even try to detect direction changes. Mice don't move that smoothly - you could be moving left, but the up/down is constantly jittering which will look like direction change. You will need to add smoothing to have a shot at this.

Comment: thank you this is working fine!
Can you please help me with adding an extra code? I would like to expand it so it call doCopy() every 2 second regadles if the mouse stop or not + this what is doing just now?

Comment: Do you want to record the mouse position every 2 seconds even if the mouse is completely still? Or only every 2 seconds while it moves, plus record it at the moment it stops?

Comment: every 2 seconds while it moves plus moment when it stops

Comment: @mgalesic OK, I added the code to do that - but note that I have not tested it. What it does is, if it's been more than 2 seconds since the last `doCopy()` then run one at that moment. If the mouse is still, nothing will happen. Note also that you'll get some duplicate notifications, not too many though.

Comment: @mgalesic Modified it just a bit - main change is to run doCopy "outside" the event handler, and second change avoids one possible duplicate