# Suggestions : Mouse tracking with JQuery mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

I want to develop a script that allows me to track the mouse movements of the user and store the data without crashing the browser. The goal is to measure and analyse the interaction of the user with a simple website that only contains different HTML elements (forms, buttons, images, tables).

I am an inexperienced programmer. Therefore, I was wondering if anyone would be willing to share his experiences with mouse tracking or has some suggestions or ideas how to improve my code or offer some other ideas.

My initial idea was to develop a code that uses jQuery mousemove to measure the mouse cursor position. However, I have read that I should use mousemove with caution due to the high required processing effort. Because of that, I had the idea to use setInterval() to measure the mouse cursor position every n seconds (see below). However, I am unsure if this is a wise approach.

```
<script>

    var mousePosition;
    var mouse_time;
    var mouse_event = {};


$(document).ready(function () {
    mousePosition = {'x': 0, 'y': 0};
    $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        x_coordinate = e.pageX;
        y_coordinate = e.pageY;
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        mouse_time = Date.now();
        mouse_event = {
            x_coordinate: x_coordinate,
            y_coordinate: y_coordinate,
            mouse_time: mouse_time,
        }
        console.log(mouse_event)
    }, 3000);
});

</script>
```

Comment: maby you can use the mousestop event to save the position of move...then it will not crash the browser

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL there is no `mousestop` event

Comment: Indeed, that is a great idea. I will implement it. If there is no mousestop event, does anyone has an idea how the implement the idea behind "mousestop" or stop data collection when there is no mouse movement?

Comment: Why do you use `setInterval` you can get and store mouse position in `mousemove` event.

Comment: @NickiMaier pls see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139651/get-mouse-coordinates-when-mouse-stop-or-change-direction

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right, there is no event like that but you can make one ..kinda

Comment: @NickiMaier I would suggest that your interval approach is more reliable and performant than a 'mousestop' tracker. The latter opens up all sorts of potential false-positive/negative and performance pitfalls.

Comment: The mouse has "stopped" (ie not moved) when the current x/y coords match the previous x/y coords.  Not sure how that helps you as you would want to track how long someone "hovers" over some element as much as how/where they move the mouse.

Comment: You could apply a `throttle` on the `mousemove` event to reduce the number of events.   You only need to "avoid" every `mousemove` if your mousemove *handler* has some high processing.  Simply recording x/y position in an array (for example) would have little impact (console.log does have a small impact).

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you, that is a good point. I was already wondering if the simple recording of positions would really cause severe browser problems.

Comment: Remember that javascript is single threaded - so anything you do will have a potential impact - eg if every 3 seconds you dump an array of collected mouse movements to the console, that will take a while so everything in your UI will stop while it does it.   I'll suggest that you collect x/y(+time) in an array, then when the array reaches eg 500 entries, fire off an `ajax` request to store the data elsewhere.  The ajax request shouldn't take too long to initiate and the actual saving would be done on the server, so not affect js.  But, in principle it's pretty much the same as on an interval.

Comment: @freedomn-m Perfect! That is exactly the other point that I had no idea how to implement! This gives me a good starting point to further develop my mouse tracking code! Many thanks,